# edit button sometimes greyed out

Tags: support

For the first time, I have not been able to edit some of the questions today because the edit button became inactive. Is it because I have reached a limit (absolute, for the day, for the hour or whatever period)? Or there are too many pending review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [FAQ on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/133299). There are a lot of possible reasons, but most likely the only one that applies to you is having five suggestions pending. People don't tend to be as active over the weekend so I'm not surprised if the reviews piled up.

It does look like you had several reviewed a couple hours ago so you're probably already able to suggest again.